# How to group by with 2 different field for the below criteria

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
Name   date       sellingAmt
Raju 08-02-2017   2000
Ravi 09-02-2017   5000
Ravi 09-02-2017   2000
Raju 09-02-2107   1000
```

Expected Result

```
Name   date       sellingAmt
Raju 08-02-2017   2000
Ravi 09-02-2017   7000
Raju 09-02-2107   1000
```

Let me know how to group by this in mysql select query

Comment: `SELECT Name, 'Date', Sum(SellingAmt) sellingAmt FROM tbl GROUP BY Name, 'Date' ORDER BY 'date', sellingAmt` substitute back ticks for apostrophe.

Comment: If you're grouping by `sellingAmt`, how do you determine which name to use? Your logic is unclear: can you tell us how should we select the name and date if there are multiple entries with the same amount?

Comment: I just noticed Name is also a reserved word. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html  Perhaps we need to escape both name and date in backticks; though I can't recreate this issue on rextester.com.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pretty basic question. What part are you struggling with?

Always post what you've tried so we can look at your train of thought and try to correct the problem at it's root instead of giving you a baked solution!

1. Date (and I just see name is as well) is a keyword/reserved word so out of habit I use the ` to escape them.
2. I used sellingAmt Desc as the order by since it appears you want those within the same date; though you could just as easily want name desc.
3. I `group by name, date` to achieve the desired results. While mySQL extends the group by so you can group on fewer values than what is in the select, I find this feature is wrongly used more often than correctly.  So I tend to error on the side of caution and always group by all fields not part of an aggregate; which is what other RDBMS systems would require of you.  In your case date and name are the unique combination to sum sellingAmt correctly and achieve your expected results.

.

```
SELECT `Name`, `Date`, Sum(SellingAmt) sellingAmt 
FROM {tblName}
GROUP BY `Name`, `Date` 
ORDER BY `date`, sellingAmt Desc
```

Replace `{tblname}` with your table name.

Comment: If we did a group by with date. Ravi 09-02-2017   7000
Raju 09-02-2107   1000 . This record grouped and merged as single record.  Please check my Expected resullt.

Comment: So you need to add name to your group by.... why doesn't the above work?  
I added element 3 but left the SQL unchanged.  It seemingly meets your expected results. Here's a [RexTester Demo](http://rextester.com/FQGA48657)

Comment: SELECT Name, `Date`, Sum(SellingAmt) sellingAmt 
FROM {tblName}
GROUP BY Name, `Date` 
ORDER BY `date`, sellingAmt Desc This query result for the above question returns 2 records. But my expected result should return 3 record. Please create table for the above examples and check it.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this situation;  http://rextester.com/CGTSA55427  Are you sure your sample data is correct?  Look at the link: I've added your query substituting the table generated and it returns 3 records.  I thought Maybe since date/name are reserved words you need the backticks around them; otherwise maybe it's just returning and grouping on the current date.... but I tried it both ways and it appears to work on rextester.  So this leaves 1 of two things: 1) your sample data doesn't match 2) your version of mySQL has a configuration different leading to different results.